# Maven and subversion

Tags: svn, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am doing work on Maven and Subversion.

I have created a maven project. Now I want to point it to my repository (created by TortoiseSVN). I read in a [tutorial on Maven and Subversion](http://wiki.gxdeveloperweb.com/confluence/display/GXDEV/Maven+and+Source+Control+Management+in+Subversion) that I should change the `pom.xml` file. Following these instructions, I have added an `scm` tag, like this:

```
<scm>
<connection>scm:svn:svn+ssh://file:///E:/my-app-repos/trunk</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:svn:svn+ssh://file:///E:/my-app-repos/trunk</developerConnection>
<url>scm:svn:svn+ssh://file:///E:/my-app-repos/trunk</url>
</scm>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<tagBase>svn+ssh://file:///E:/my-app-reposs</tagBase>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

But then, when I a try to `mvn release:prepare`, I get an error:

```
fail to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins
```

What could be going on?

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you have a bad URL. You have `ssh+svn://file:///`. It should either be `svn://`, `ssh+svn://`, `http://`, `https://`, or `file:///`.

However, I noticed that it appears your repository is on a shared drive (drive E:). If more than one person is using this Subversion repository, you should not be using the `file://` protocol. In fact, I never use it if I don't have to. It's easy enough to start an SVN server using `svnserve`.

Take a look at [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). It's a commercial product, but there's a free version. It will setup an Apache httpd server and give you a way of configuring that server including setting up user accounts. Then, everyone can access the repository using `http://`.

The problem is that using the `file:///` protocol means that the repository has to be read/writeable by everyone in your group. That means anyone can directly manipulate the repository without going through the front end. Plus, you can end up with multiple people attempting to create a revision at the same time, and that can totally mess up your entire repository.

If Drive E: is a shared drive, don't use `file:///`. Instead, go to the Windows machine where this drive is located, and run either `svnserve` or `VisualSVN Server`. You can try installing Apache httpd yourself, but it's a tricky proposition on Unix, and very difficult on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, just a guess but it probably failed because you use a local SVN server. Actually, I'm wondering why you do that?

Try to install your SVN repo on a web server instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need an `svn+ssh` protocol to connect to a local repository (`file:///`)?  Can you try removing `svn+ssh` and see if that works.  Refer to [this](http://maven.apache.org/scm/subversion.html).

```
scm:svn:file://[hostname]/path_to_repository
```

Comment: when I am trying to following such type of syntax  then i getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You should remove svn+ssh and keep only file, this is the protocol to use, since you are accessing to local repository "file" protocol is enough.

```
scm:svn:file:///E:/my-app-repos/trunk
```

::

Check this link: http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/usage.html